# array_sum produce resultados erróneos si hay un valor TRUE, ¿cómo evitarlo o encontrar una alternativa segura?

Tags: php

Estaba probando un código en el cual mediante el uso de `array_sum` me recorra un array multidimensional y me sume la totalidad de valores de cada sub-conjunto de array.

El problema es que si el array donde supuestamente debe haber números se colase un valor booleano `TRUE`, `array_sum` asume que ese valor es igual a `1`.

Si se trata de sumar solamente los valores numéricos, los resultados no serían conformes a la realidad:

```
$arrTest = array(
                    "Normal" => array(1,1), 
                    "Anormal" => array(TRUE,1),
                    "Con string" => array("+",1,1),
                    "Con false" => array(1,FALSE,1),
                    "Con negativo" => array(1,2,-1),
                    "Con Problema económico" => array(1,-100),

                );
foreach ($arrTest as $k=>$v) {
    if (is_array($v)){
          echo "La suma de $k es: ".array_sum($v).PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
La suma de Normal es: 2
La suma de Anormal es: 2
La suma de Con string es: 2
La suma de Con false es: 2
La suma de Con negativo es: 2
La suma de Con Problema económico es: -99
```

La salida para la clave `Anormal` debería ser `1`, sin embargo, es `2`.

¿Cómo podría evitar esto? ¿Hay alguna alternativa para `array_sum`?

**P.D.:** Teniendo en cuenta que es lunes, espero que en ninguno de uds se cumpla el contenido del último array :)

Answer (score 1):

Si revisamos la documentación de la conversión desde boleanos a números vemos lo siguiente:

> [Desde booleanos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting.from-boolean)
>
> FALSE producirá 0 (cero), y TRUE producirá 1 (uno).

¿Qué está sucediendo con la conversion a número?

```
$arrTest = array(
    "Normal" => array(1,1), // 1+1 = 2
    "Anormal" => array(TRUE,1), // 1+1 = 2
    "Con string" => array("+",1,1), // 0+1+1 = 2
    "Con false" => array(1,FALSE,1), // 1+0+1 = 2
    "Con negativo" => array(1,2,-1), // 1+2+(-1) = 2
    "Con Problema económico" => array(1,-100), // 1-100 = -99
);
```

---

Para solventarlo podrías utilizar [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php) junto con [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-numeric.php)

Ejemplo:

```
$arrTest = array(
                    "Normal" => array(1,1), 
                    "Anormal" => array(TRUE,1),
                    "Con string" => array("+",1,1),
                    "Con false" => array(1,FALSE,1),
                    "Con negativo" => array(1,2,-1),
                    "Con Problema económico" => array(1,-100),

                );
foreach ($arrTest as $k=>$v) {
    if (is_array($v)){
          echo "La suma de $k es: ".array_sum(array_filter($v, 'is_numeric')).PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
La suma de Normal es: 2
La suma de Anormal es: 1
La suma de Con string es: 2
La suma de Con false es: 2
La suma de Con negativo es: 2
La suma de Con Problema económico es: -99
```

---

Answer (score 1):

`array_sum` intenta parsear todos los valores dentro del array a su equivalente numérico. En el caso de los boolean 1 para **TRUE** y 0 para **FALSE**.
La forma mas fácil que tienes es utilizar un filtro, para trabajar únicamente con los valores numéricos dentro del array.

Utilizando el mismo ejemplo que tienes, `array_filter` sería la opción mas viable.

```
$arrTest = array(
                    "Normal" => array(1,1), 
                    "Anormal" => array(TRUE,1),
                    "Con string" => array("+",1,1),
                    "Con false" => array(1,FALSE,1),
                    "Con negativo" => array(1,2,-1),
                    "Con Problema económico" => array(1,-100),

                );
foreach ($arrTest as $k=>$v) {
    if (is_array($v)){
          echo "La suma de $k es: ".array_sum(array_filter($v, "is_numeric")).PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

> Puedes agregar el valor que retorna la función array_filter a una variable si lo deseas tratar, o si quieres que el código se muestre un poco mas desglosado.

El resulta de esta consulta sería:

```
La suma de Normal es: 2
La suma de Anormal es: 1
La suma de Con string es: 2
La suma de Con false es: 2
La suma de Con negativo es: 2
La suma de Con Problema económico es: -99
```

Comment: Creo que me adelante por unos minutos, hehehe

Answer (score 1):

Para el caso que tienes la respuesta de **Xerif** se adapta perfectamente con mínimos cambios.

Una alternativa, *aunque implica una función adicional*, y se puede usar para construir filtros más complejos. Puede ser [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php).

Ejemplo:

```
$arrTest = array(
    "Normal"       => array(1, 1), 
    "Anormal"      => array(true, 1),
    "Con string"   => array("+", 1, 1),
    "Con false"    => array(1, false, 1),
    "Con negativo" => array(1, 2, -1),
    "Con Problema económico" => array(1, -100),
);

function suma($result, $item)
{
    $result += (is_numeric($item))? $item : 0;
    return $result;
}

foreach ($arrTest as $k => $v) {
    if (is_array($v)){
          echo "La suma de $k es: ".array_reduce($v, 'suma') . PHP_EOL;      
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
La suma de Normal es: 2
La suma de Anormal es: 1
La suma de Con string es: 2
La suma de Con false es: 2
La suma de Con negativo es: 2
La suma de Con Problema económico es: -99
```

Para probarlo: [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1e5513d554bf7430bc842d2228cf15f60dc16b76)

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la función gettype() para conocer el tipo de datos de cada valor de cada subconjunto de arrays y filtrando por condición lo puedes solucionar. Por ejemplo, filtrando solamente los del tipo integer:

```
$arrTest = array(
   "Normal" => array(1,1), 
   "Anormal" => array(TRUE,1),
   "Con string" => array("+",1,1),
   "Con false" => array(1,FALSE,1),
   "Con negativo" => array(1,2,-1),
   "Con Problema económico" => array(1,-100),

);

foreach ($arrTest as $k=>$v) {
   if (is_array($v)){
      $suma = 0;
      foreach ($v as $value) {
         if(gettype($value)== 'integer'){$suma += $value;}
      }

      echo "La suma de $k es: ".$suma.'<br>';
   }
}
```